# Error: "The xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable."

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

In my code I have the following Linq Query:

```
IQueryable<Data> charts = (from report in ctx.Charts group report by new 
    { 
        Name = report.ChartTitle.ChartType.ChartCategory.CategoryName,
        id = report.ChartTitle.ChartType.ChartCategory.ChartCategoryId, 
        Period = report.Period 
    } into d
    select new Data
    {
        Name = d.Key.Name,
        Id = d.Key.id,
        Period = d.Key.Period,            
        Reports = from r in d group r by new 
        { Title = r.ChartTitle.Name, id = r.ChartTitle.ChartTitleId } into rs
        select new Report
        {
            Title = rs.Key.Title,
            Id = rs.Key.id,
            Charts = (from c in rs group c by new 
                    { 
                        ChartId = c.ChartId, 
                        FiscalYear = c.FiscalYear, 
                        ModifiedDate = c.ChartView.ModifiedDate, 
                        Function = c.Function.DisplayName, 
                        ChartData=c.ChartView.ViewData
                    } into cs
                    select new ChartInfo 
                    { 
                        ChartId = cs.Key.ChartId, 
                        FiscalYear = cs.Key.FiscalYear,
                        ModifiedDate = cs.Key.ModifiedDate, 
                        Function = cs.Key.Function, 
                        ChartData=cs.Key.ChartData 
                    })
    }});
```

In the above code if I exclude the "ChartData" field (which is of XML datatype), the query executes fine. But when ever I include this field it throws the following error :"The xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable."

Let me know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't group by XML types.  This is a SQL restriction, not a LINQ-to-SQL retriction.  (See [Group by on XML column field with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144543/group-by-on-xml-column-field-with-linq) and [select an xml type column in select query with group by SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222212/select-an-xml-type-column-in-select-query-with-group-by-sql-server-2008))

Do you *need* to group by the XML column? The alternative would be to group by your other columns and then select the first XML value as a result.

```
Charts = (from c in rs group c by new  
{
    ChartId = c.ChartId,
    FiscalYear = c.FiscalYear,
    ModifiedDate = c.ChartView.ModifiedDate,
    Function = c.Function.DisplayName,
} into cs                     
select new ChartInfo
{
    ChartId = cs.Key.ChartId,
    FiscalYear = cs.Key.FiscalYear,
    ModifiedDate = cs.Key.ModifiedDate,
    Function = cs.Key.Function,
    ChartData=cs.Value.FirstOrDefault().ChartData
})
```

When using LINQ-to-SQL the items being grouped are still accessible - you don't need to include every 'selected' property / column in the group by` clause like you would in SQL.

Comment: Hey Kirk, Thank you for your response. This solution worked for me with a slight change...I have to made the following change:
Instead of : 
ChartData=cs.Value.FirstOrDefault().ChartData
I had used
ChartData=cs.FirstOrDefault().ChartData

becuase, I didn't find the property "Value".

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell us what is the actual datatype of the ChartData, but from the error you are describing it looks like the problem is that whatever this datatype is it does not implement the `IComparable` interface which is a required interface if you want instances of the datatype to be comparable

Comment: Can you please explain little more? ChartData is of type XML in the database table.

Comment: i tried to use IEqualityComparer<ChartInfo> but go the following error message ....
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[test.Model.ChartInfo] Distinct[ChartInfo](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[test.Model.ChartInfo], System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[test.Model.ChartInfo])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.